# How to confine Wi-Fi driver to use IEEE 802.11ac mode and lower?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, wifi, drivers

I have a notebook with wi-fi chip that supports IEEE 802.11ax as most. Below is `lspci` output.

```
5d:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz (rev 1a)
```

And when I used it in Windows OS I figured out that the download/upload speed was much faster (twice or thrice) when I prohibited to use **ax** mode and allow to use **ac** and lower. Maybe owing to some hardware bug.

Some days ago I installed Fedora on the same notebook and have come across the same speed problem. Download and upload speed (speedtest.net) is extremely slow, around 10-20Mbs instead of 80-90Mbs.

I want to solve my problem the way I solved it in Windows. I want to confine linux wi-fi driver not to use **ax** mode.

I figured out that now driver does use ax mode. Below is result of `iw dev link` command:

```
        freq: 5180
        RX: 58469848 bytes (52247 packets)
        TX: 6355149 bytes (26551 packets)
        signal: -59 dBm
        rx bitrate: 408.3 MBit/s 80MHz HE-MCS 8 HE-NSS 1 HE-GI 1 HE-DCM 0
        tx bitrate: 510.3 MBit/s 80MHz HE-MCS 10 HE-NSS 1 HE-GI 1 HE-DCM 0
```

Compare the difference:

Windows:
[image: Windows]

Linux:
[image: Linux]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a text file named e.g. `/etc/modprobe.d/disable-11ax.conf` (you can pick any name, as long as it has the `.conf` suffix and is placed in the correct directory) with the following contents:

```
options iwlwifi disable_11ax=1
```

If your Linux distribution loads the `iwlwifi` driver in initramfs, you will need to update your initramfs file to ensure the setting will take effect at boot.

The initramfs update procedure is different in various distributions:

- on Fedora, `dracut -f` seems to be the right command.
- on Debian/Ubuntu/Mint, `update-initramfs -u` does the job.
- on Arch, the command is apparently `mkinitcpio`... but I don't know too much on Arch.

Comment: Thank you very much! For me it has helped without changing initramfs. How can anyone who uses Fedora knows if iwlwifi is loaded in initramfs?

Comment: You could use a script that lists or extracts the contents of your initramfs file (e.g. `lsinitramfs`, `lsinitrd` or `unmkinitramfs`, depending on distribution), and see if `iwlwifi.ko` is included in there. If it is, then hardware autodetection could cause it be loaded before the root filesystem is mounted.